# Android tooltip not showing all toolTipText

Tags: android, tooltip

I want to see all of the text from the tooltip.

```
mView.setToolTipText(view, "A long toolTipText");
```

[image]

Comment: So, I've fixed it using my own custom view, but if anyone can solve this in some way **(without using a custom view)** it would still be appreciated.